# Linking source file in org mode with specific revision

Tags: org-mode, org-link, version-control

I need org-mode version of links like this `https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/cd2c1561636597c67edbf3daf10388e5385a93fc/etc/NEWS#L1119` for local files inside local repo.

A way to specify not only the line and file that I want to link locally but also its version so when the file visited the specified revision will be displayed.

Example: `file:my_versioned_file.el::<GIT_HESH>::<LINE_NUMBER>` should visit local `my_versioned_file.el` file at `<GIT_HESH>` revision and line `<LINE_NUMBER>`

Comment: Why do you need a different version? Doesn't that link work as is?

Comment: @NickD added example and clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification: you might be able to define a [new link type](https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html#Adding-Hyperlink-Types) to do what you want, but AFAIK org-mode does not provide such a type out of the box.

Comment: But a quick search uncovered [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-git-link.html).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it. Not sure if it supports links to lines but gonna look into it.